# Formatting error messages in custom model validator .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

In a .NET Core 3.x application, I have a model like the following where a custom validation attribute `[CustomValidator]` is used. The error messages returned for `CustomValidator` doesn't have a `$.` prefix whereas the built-in JSON validator returns with the prefix. I'd like to have them consistent (either with `$.` prefix all the time or not). Any idea how could this be done?

Example model:

```
public class Dto 
{
    public float Price {get; set;}
    [CustomValidator] public int? EntityID {get; set;}
}
```

where `[CustomValidator]` is a custom validation attribute which does something like this

```
public class CustomValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

          var isValid = CheckSomething(...);
          return isValid
                ? ValidationResult.Success
                : new ValidationResult($"Invalid value for Entity");
    }

}
```

I validate model in the `Controller.Action` with

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

For the input:

```
{
  "Price" : "abc"
}
```

it returns

```
{
...
    "errors": {
        "$.price": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Single. Path: $.price | LineNumber: 7 | BytePositionInLine: 21."
        ]
    }
}
```

whereas for the input:

```
{
  "Price" : 1.0,
  "EntityID": -1,
}
```

it returns

```
{
...
    "errors": {
        "EntityID": [
            "Invalid value for Entity"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'd like it to have the `errors` always having consistent property names e.g. `Price` and `EntityID` instead of `$.price` and `EntityID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$.` prefix is part of the json path contained in `JsonException`. You can see it in the source code of the default json input formatter here [SystemTextJsonInputFormatter](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Formatters/SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.cs).

So technically to normalize that path before it being passed to the method `ModelState.TryAddModelError`, you need of course to modify that path somehow. It's quite complicated that way. Instead you can configure a custom `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` for your final `ProblemDetails` result. Although this way you may take a tradeoff of performance hit especially when the validation error occurs frequently and there are a lot of errors involved. But I think it's not a common case in reality. The idea of this approach is to modify the `ModelState` by trying to swap out all the entries having key prefixed with `$.` and replace them with the ones having that key prefix trimmed off.

You can configure that response factory by configuring the `ApiBehaviorOptions`, like this:

```
//inside Startup.ConfigureServices
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(o => {
            //we need to call this original factory inside our custom factory
            var originalFactory = o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory;
            o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context => {   
                //get all the keys prefixed with $. (which should be related to json errors)                 
                var jsonPathKeys = context.ModelState.Keys.Where(e => e.StartsWith("$.")).ToList();
                foreach(var key in jsonPathKeys)
                {
                    var normalizedKey = key.Substring(2);
                    foreach (var error in context.ModelState[key].Errors)
                    {
                        if (error.Exception != null)
                        {
                            context.ModelState.TryAddModelException(normalizedKey, error.Exception);
                        }
                        context.ModelState.TryAddModelError(normalizedKey, error.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                    context.ModelState.Remove(key);
                }                    
                return originalFactory(context);
            };
        });
```