# Override the response body of RequiredAttribute in DataAnnotation in .NET Core / .NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-5

After adding the required attribute to API Request model and then when the request body is invalid I get the response as

```
{
   "type":"<type_URL>",
   "title":"One or more validation errors occurred.",
   "status":400,
   "traceId":"<trace_id_guid>",
   "errors":{
      "Id":[
         "Value is required"
      ]
   }
}
```

I would like to alter this body to something like,

```
{
    "status":400,
    "errors":[
       "Value is required"
    ]
 }
```

Is it possible to override some function to get this result?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67697113/formatting-error-messages-in-custom-model-validator-net-core

Comment: that is not what I required as it would return TraceId

Comment: You have to show the API that returns the error response, if you need some help

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom ValidationError model which contains the returned fields, then try to use the action filter to handle the Validation failure error response. Check the following sample code:

1. Create custom ValidationError model which contains the returned fields:

   ```
    public class ValidationResultModel
    {
        public string status { get; }

        public List<ValidationError> Errors { get; }

        public ValidationResultModel(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            status = "400";
            Errors = modelState.Keys
                    .SelectMany(key => modelState[key].Errors.Select(x => new ValidationError(key, x.ErrorMessage)))
                    .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class ValidationError
    { 
        public string Field { get; }

        public string Message { get; }

        public ValidationError(string field, string message)
        {
            Field = field != string.Empty ? field : null;
            Message = message;
        }
    }
   ```
2. Create custom IActionResult. By default, when display the validation error, it will return BadRequestObjectResult and the HTTP status code is 400. Here we could change the Http Status code.

   ```
    public class ValidationFailedResult : ObjectResult
    {
        public ValidationFailedResult(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
            : base(new ValidationResultModel(modelState))
        {
            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
        }
    }
   ```
3. Create Custom Action Filter attribute:

   ```
    public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Result = new ValidationFailedResult(context.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
   ```
4. Change the default response type to SerializableError in Startup.ConfigureServices:

   ```
        services.AddControllers().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
        {
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
            {
                var result = new ValidationFailedResult(context.ModelState);

                // TODO: add `using System.Net.Mime;` to resolve MediaTypeNames
                result.ContentTypes.Add(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);
                result.ContentTypes.Add(MediaTypeNames.Application.Xml);

                return result;
            };
        });
   ```
5. Add the custom action filter (`ValidateModel`) at the action method or controller.

   ```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [ValidateModel]
    public class ToDoController : ControllerBase
    {
   ```
6. Create a Model with DataAnnotations:

   ```
    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; } 
    }
   ```
7. API controller:

   ```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [ValidateModel]
    public class ToDoController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("AddUser")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddUser([FromBody] User model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = "userID: " + model.UserId + " UserName: " + model.UserName;
                return Ok(result);
            }
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
   ```

After running the application, the result like this:

[image]

Comment: What about the response that I get when I send an invalid json. Will this allow me to override that?